# Why does "?a=a" get added to the back of my URL on GET?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, url, get

I use a post GET request with `action="/sact/${searchp}/"` in order to submit an user search query.

```
var searchp = search.querySelector("input.search-input").value;
// returns the normal value

document.body.innerHTML += `<form id="jsForm" action="/sact/${search}/" method="GET"><input type="hidden" name="a" value="a"></form>`;
document.getElementById("jsForm").submit();
```

This redirects here:

```
router.get('/sact/:where', async (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('search');
});
```

I can't figure out why /?a=a gets added to the back of the URL every time it gets submitted. How do I remove it?

Comment: use the `POST` rather than the `GET` method if you don't want any query strings in your URL after form submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `document.getElementById("jsForm").submit();` will send the form on the URL as query parameters because you are using `method="GET"`

The `a=a` is from this field `<input type="hidden" name="a" value="a">` is hidden on the HTML but still will be send on the URL

if you want to "hide" you could use `method="POST"` won't be visible on the URL

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense. Thank you